# only first of multiple file inputs responds to event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have number of forms on a page and each one has a file input. When the user chooses a file, I would like to print the name of the selected file in the `<span class="fileNameBox"></span>` that is inside the relevant form.

I'm having two problems:

1. Only the first input responds by displaying the selected filename.
2. When clicking the image inside the `<label>` for a particular input, the filename is always displayed in the first "fileNameBox", rather than the one associated with the `<label>`.

How can I remedy those two problems?

```js
$(function() {
  document.querySelector('input[name="file[]"]').onchange = function(e) {
    var files = this.files;
    var filename = files[0].name;
    $(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html(filename);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
      <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
      <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' id="uploadFile" />
    </div>
    <label class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 control-label" for="uploadFile">
      <img src="images/photoIconOn.png" alt="" class="uploadFileImg" />
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
      <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
      <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' id="uploadFile" />
    </div>
    <label class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 control-label" for="uploadFile">
      <img src="images/photoIconOn.png" alt="" class="uploadFileImg" />
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
      <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
      <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' id="uploadFile" />
    </div>
    <label class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 control-label" for="uploadFile">
      <img src="images/photoIconOn.png" alt="" class="uploadFileImg" />
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What happens? How does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: it always print the file's name in the first form / class="fileNameBox"

Answer (score 1):

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) "*returns the first element within the document... that matches the specified group of selectors.*" So, only the first matching input on your page is returned.

You could use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and attach a listener to each element returned. But, since you are already using jQuery, I suggest using jQuery to select your inputs:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input.form-control').on('change', function(e) {
    var files = this.files,
        filename = files[0].name;
    $(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html(filename);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
      <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
      <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
      <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
      <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
      <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
      <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

### Edit

Additionally, it seems that you're referring to the fact that clicking a `<label>` image only selects the first input. This is because all of your inputs have the same ID. IDs need to be unique, like so:

```
<input type='file' name='file[]' id="uploadFile1" />
<input type='file' name='file[]' id="uploadFile2" />
<input type='file' name='file[]' id="uploadFile3" />
```

As an alternative, I have removed the IDs altogether and placed each `<input>` *inside* its `<label>`. For reference, see the [examples for "label" at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Examples).

Please see the working example below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input.form-control').on('change', function(e) {
    var files = this.files,
      filename = files[0].name;
    $(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html(filename);
  });
});
```

```css
img.uploadFileImg {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 control-label">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/abstract/2/" alt="" class="uploadFileImg" />
        <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
        <input type='file' name='file[]' class='form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 control-label">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/abstract/2/" alt="" class="uploadFileImg" />
        <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
        <input type='file' name='file[]' class='form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 control-label">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/abstract/2/" alt="" class="uploadFileImg" />
        <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
        <input type='file' name='file[]' class='form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding. Did you click "run code snippet" above? Each "fileNameBox" gets the name of the file chosen for its respective input. [Here is a screen-shot of the output.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iUi8K.jpg) How does this differ from your expected result?

Comment: Hi, i see that I didn't copy the image part - Instead of input field for the file uploader, I'm using image "photoIconOn.png". here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820258/display-file-name-with-number-of-forms

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. Please see my edit, above. Does that help to clarify?