# display file name with number of forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have number of forms on a page and each one has a file input. When the user chooses a file, I would like to print the name of the selected file in the `<span class="fileNameBox"></span>` that is inside the relevant form.

**Instead of input field for the file uploader, I'm using image "photoIconOn.png".**

Why does it always print the file's name in the first form / class="fileNameBox" ?

JS:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('input.file-field').on('change', function(e) {
        var files = this.files,
            filename = files[0].name;
        $(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html(filename);
      });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" >תוכן</label>  
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="form-control comment-field" name="comment[text]" rows="1" ></textarea>
            <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
            <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' id="uploadFile" style="display: none"/>
        </div>

        <label class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 control-label" for="uploadFile">
            <img src="images/photoIconOn.png" alt="" class="uploadFileImg"/>
        </label>
    </div>                      
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="textinput"></label>  
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary submit" >SEND</button>
        </div>
    </div>  

</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" >תוכן</label>  
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="form-control comment-field" name="comment[text]" rows="1" ></textarea>
            <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
            <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' id="uploadFile" style="display: none"/>
        </div>

        <label class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 control-label" for="uploadFile">
            <img src="images/photoIconOn.png" alt="" class="uploadFileImg"/>
        </label>
    </div>                      
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="textinput"></label>  
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary submit" >SEND</button>
        </div>
    </div>  

</form>
```

Comment: can you output in the console your " vat files" please

Comment: Seems to me because you are getting the filename like this `filename = files[0].name;` so it is always going to get the first value of the array

Comment: Though, I noticed you have duplicate ID's for the input file...`id="uploadFile"`

Comment: What script are you using to "open" the "choose file" dialog? I have a suspicion that your issue lies within the fact that you are using `display:none;` on the upload input.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am going to answer this, though what you have should be working.
I copy and pasted your code into a fiddle and everything works. The only thing I changed was how I got the filename since I don't how you are doing it while hiding the file input.

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L5gu9vhL/1/

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" ></label>  
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
        <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
        <input type='file' name='file[]' class='file-field' id="myid"/>
    </div>

    <label class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 control-label" for="uploadFile">
        <img src="images/photoIconOn.png" alt="" class="uploadFileImg"/>
    </label>
</div>                      
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="textinput"></label>  
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary submit" >SEND</button>
    </div>
</div>  

</form>
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" ></label>  
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
        <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
        <input type='file' name='file[]' class='file-field' id="myid"/>
    </div>

    <label class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 control-label" for="uploadFile">
        <img src="images/photoIconOn.png" alt="" class="uploadFileImg"/>
    </label>
</div>                      
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="textinput"></label>  
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary submit" >SEND</button>
    </div>
</div>  

</form>
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {
  $('input.file-field').on('change', function(e) {
   var filename = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html(filename);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but still not workung. I'm hidding the file field and display image instead. clicking on it open my brower (for uploading images...). please see screenshot - 
http://postimg.org/image/65587muxf/